# Using Column Alias in WHERE clause in SQL, getting 'Unrecognized Name' Error. What's the workaround?

Tags: sql, group-by, column-alias

[image]

I have put `COUNT(*) AS num_of_trips` in the `SELECT` Clause.

Now, I want to use `num_of_trips > 30` in `WHERE` Clause but it gives "unrecognized name" error.

I also tried to workaround it by putting the same argument in `WHERE` clause as:
`ROUND(AVG(tripduration/60),2) > 30` but that also gave error.

Comment: aggregated values may be used AFTER group by in the HAVING clause

Comment: cannot reference the alias name "num_of_trips" in `WHERE`  because `SELECT` is evaluated after `WHERE` -- one workaround is to repeat the expression used in `SELECT` directly in the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

Aggregated values may be used **after** the `GROUP BY` in the `HAVING` clause

```
select column1, count(*) as num_of_trips 
from table1
where column2 = 1 -- NO aggregates available here
group by column1
having count(*) > 30  -- aggregated values are available here
```

The `WHERE` clause filters the rows *before aggregation*; the `HAVING` clause filters the grouped data and aggregated values may only be referenced in this clause.